# How to choose when fortune wheel stop in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is a lot of code about normal fortune wheels but I can't find anything about how to control where the wheel stops?

My fortune wheel should work like this: 1->5,8->12 have a 90% chance that the arrow stops there, 6 has a 1% chance, others have 9%.

And I need it to accumulate and increase during play, example: after 1 turn arrow have 2% chance of stop at 6 instead of 1%.

```
public List<int> prize;
public List<AnimationCurve> animationCurves;

private bool spinning;    
private float anglePerItem;    
private int randomTime;
private int itemNumber;

BoxCollider2D m_collider;
void Start()
{

    spinning = false;
    anglePerItem = 360/prize.Count;      

}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && !spinning) {

        randomTime = Random.Range (1, 4);
        itemNumber = Random.Range (0, prize.Count);
        float maxAngle = 1080 * randomTime + (itemNumber * anglePerItem);

        StartCoroutine (SpinTheWheel (5 * randomTime, maxAngle));
    }
}
IEnumerator SpinTheWheel (float time, float maxAngle)
{
    spinning = true;

    float timer = 0.0f;        
    float startAngle = transform.eulerAngles.z;        
    maxAngle = maxAngle - startAngle;

    int animationCurveNumber = Random.Range (0, animationCurves.Count);
    Debug.Log ("Animation Curve No. : " + animationCurveNumber);

    while (timer < time) {
    //to calculate rotation
        float angle = maxAngle * animationCurves [animationCurveNumber].Evaluate (timer / time) ;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0.0f, 0.0f, angle + startAngle);
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return 0;
    }

    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0.0f, 0.0f, maxAngle + startAngle);
    spinning = false;
        Debug.Log( itemNumber);
    Debug.Log ("Prize: " + prize [itemNumber]);//use prize[itemNumnber] as per requirement
}
```

[image: Fortune wheel]

Comment: Your probabilities don't seem to add up correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: Your percentages don't sum up

if as you describe `1..5` and `8..12` together cover `90%` then there is only `10%` left to share between `6` and `7`.

So from your description each `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`8`,`9`,`10`,`11` and `12` would have an indivdual percentage of `9%`. `6` would have `1%` and since only `9%` are left also `7` would have `9%`.

I leave it at this for now but you probably will want to fix these weights according to your needs.

---

What you want then is a weighted random e.g. like

```
private Dictionary<int, int> weights = new Dictionary<int, int>
{
    // Value | Weight TODO: Make sure these sum up to 100
    {1,        9},
    {2,        9},
    {3,        9},
    {4,        9},
    {5,        9},
    {6,        1},
    {7,        9},
    {8,        9},
    {9,        9},
    {10,       9},
    {11,       9},
    {12,       9}
};

// for storing the weighted options
private readonly List<int> weightedOptions = new List<int>();

private void Start()
{
    // first fill the randomResults accordingly to the given weights
    weightedOptions.Clear();

    foreach (var kvp in weights)
    {
        // add kvp.Key to the list kvp.value times
        for (var i = 0; i < kvp.Value; i++)
        {
            weightedOptions.Add(kvp.Key);
        }
    }
}

public int GetRandomNumber()
{
    // get a random index from 0 to 99 (or how much items you have - 1)
    var randomIndex = Random.Range(0, weightedOptions.Count);
    // get the according value
    return weightedOptions[randomIndex];
}
```

---

It is unclear how you then want to implement

> after 1 turn arrow have 2% chance of stop at 12 instead of 1%

you can't increase the probability of one single number without decreasing the probability of one or all other numbers at the same time since they always sum up to 100%.

So first think about: Which number(s) should increase its(their) probability and which one(s) should decrease in exchange?

---

#### With your code

Now having your actual code I would modify it and implement before mentioned weighted list and then make the rotation pure angle based like

```
// instead of a Dictionary in order to be able to adjust the values via the Inspector
// (there are also more fancy solutions like SerializedDictionary with a special drawer for this purpose)
[Serializable]
public class WeightedValue
{
    public int Value;
    public int Weight;

    public WeightedValue(int value, int weight)
    {
        Value = value;
        Weight = weight;
    }
}

// just a struct to get both the index and value at the same time
private struct RandomInfo
{
    public readonly int Index;
    public readonly int Value;
    public readonly IReadOnlyList<int> WeightedOptions;
    public readonly int AmountOfFullRotations;
    
    public RandomInfo(List<int> weightedOptions, int minRotations, int maxRotations)
    {
        WeightedOptions = weightedOptions;

        // get a random index
        Index= Random.Range(0, WeightedOptions.Count);
        // get the actual according value
        Value = WeightedOptions[Index];

        AmountOfFullRotations = Random.Range(minRotations, maxRotations);
    }
}


public List<WeightedValue> PricesWithWeights = new List<WeightedValue>
{
    //               Value | Weight TODO: Make sure these sum up to 100
    new WeightedValue(1,        9),
    new WeightedValue(2,        9),
    new WeightedValue(3,        9),
    new WeightedValue(4,        9),
    new WeightedValue(5,        9),
    new WeightedValue(6,        1),
    new WeightedValue(7,        9),
    new WeightedValue(8,        9),
    new WeightedValue(9,        9),
    new WeightedValue(10,       9),
    new WeightedValue(11,       9),
    new WeightedValue(12,       9)
};

// minimum full rotations
// adjust in the Inspector
public int MinRotations = 2;

// maximum full rotations
// adjust in the Inspector
public int MaxRotations = 6;

// seconds one complete rotation shall take
// adjust in the Inspector
public float SpinDuration = 5;

// you can't assign this directly since you want it weighted
private readonly List<int> _weightedList = new List<int>();

private bool _spinning;
private float _anglePerItem;

private void Start()
{
    _spinning = false;
    _anglePerItem = 360f / PricesWithWeights.Count;

    _weightedList.Clear();

    // first fill the randomResults accordingly to the given wheights
    foreach (var kvp in PricesWithWeights)
    {
        // add kvp.Key to the list kvp.value times
        for (var i = 0; i < kvp.Weight; i++)
        {
            _weightedList.Add(kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    // spinning is less expensive to check so do it first
    if (!_spinning && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpinTheWheel());
        // or pass in a callback to actually do something with the random result
        //StartCoroutine(SpinTheWheel(OptionalCallbackMethod));
    }
}

//private void OptionalCallbackMethod(int result)
//{
//    Debug.Log($"Congratulations! You just have won option {result}!")
//}

// Selects a random target option and a random amount of full spins before reaching the target
// then internally runs the parameterized overload
private IEnumerator SpinTheWheel(Action<int> onResult = null)
{
    // What you had
    //itemNumber = Random.Range(0, prize.Count); 
    // returns a random index .. not the actual value at this index

    // this now has all information we need
    var randomInfo = new RandomInfo(_weightedList, MinRotations, MaxRotations);

    var itemNumberAngle = randomInfo.Index * _anglePerItem;
    var currentAngle = transform.eulerAngles.z;
    // reset/clamp currentAngle to a value 0-360 since itemNumberAngle will be in this range
    while (currentAngle >= 360)
    {
        currentAngle -= 360;
    }
    while (currentAngle < 0)
    {
        currentAngle += 360;
    }

    // Now we can compose the actual total target rotation
    // depends on your setup of course .. For my example below I will use it negative (rotation clockwise) like
    var targetAngle = -(itemNumberAngle + 360f * randomInfo.AmountOfFullRotations);

    Debug.Log($"Will spin {randomInfo.AmountOfFullRotations} times before ending at {randomInfo.Value} with an angle of {itemNumberAngle}", this);
    Debug.Log($"The odds for this were {PricesWithWeights[randomInfo.Index].Weight / (float)PricesWithWeights.Sum(p => p.Weight):P} !");

    yield return SpinTheWheel(currentAngle, targetAngle, randomInfo.AmountOfFullRotations * SpinDuration, randomInfo.Value, onResult);
}

// spins the wheel from the given fromAngle until the given toAngle within withinSeconds seconds
// using an eased in and eased out rotation
private IEnumerator SpinTheWheel(float fromAngle, float toAngle, float withinSeconds, int result, Action<int> onResult = null)
{
    _spinning = true;

    var passedTime = 0f;
    while (passedTime < withinSeconds)
    {
        // here you can use any mathematical curve for easing the animation
        // in this case Smoothstep uses a simple ease-in and ease-out
        // so the rotation starts slow, reaches a maximum in the middle and ends slow
        // you could also e.g. use SmoothDamp to start fast and only end slow
        // and you can stack them to amplify their effect
        var lerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, (Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, passedTime / withinSeconds)));

        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, Mathf.Lerp(fromAngle, toAngle, lerpFactor));
        passedTime += Time.deltaTime;

        yield return null;
    }

    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, toAngle);
    _spinning = false;

    Debug.Log("Prize: " + result);

    // if provided invoke the given callback
    onResult?.Invoke(result);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, stupid me -.-, didn't think about sum up to 100. About 12, it was mistake, it should be 6.

Comment: Sorry, I'm noob :( , I'm try to add your code to mine but fail. Could you help me with it? @derHugo

Comment: @TháiKhánh don't feel stupid we are all here to learn ;) Please see my updates

Comment: Didn't expect this much detail answer. Thank you, thank you. You are the best.