# how to slow a rotating object in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I am trying to write a wheel of fortune type thing. I would like the wheel to spin for a set period of time and then slow to a stop at a random location.

What I have so far works, but the stop is too abrupt. Using Slerp in there somewhere would probably solve the problem. But I am having trouble getting it to work as well at ensuring that the wheel only spins clockwise!

```
 public class WheelOptions : MonoBehaviour
 {
     [SerializeField] int spinDuration = 5;
     [SerializeField] int seedValue = 5;
     [SerializeField] SectionColors[] sectionColors;

     Vector3 targetPosition;

     bool isSpinning = false;
     bool hasSpun = false;
     int currentSpin = 0;

     void Start()
     {
         targetPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 5), 0f, Random.Range(-5, 5));
     }

     public void SpinWheel()
     {

         isSpinning = true;
         hasSpun = false;

         targetPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-5, 5), 0f, Random.Range(-5, 5));

         StartCoroutine( StopTimer() );
     }

     void Update()
     {
         transform.position = new Vector3(0f, 0, 0f);
    
         if (isSpinning == true)
         {
             if (currentSpin < 360)
             {
                 currentSpin++;
             }
             else currentSpin = 0;

             this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, currentSpin, 0);
         }
         else if(hasSpun == true)
         {
             Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition - transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)); 
             transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, rotation.y, 0, rotation.w);
         }
     }

     IEnumerator StopTimer()
     {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(spinDuration);

         isSpinning = false;
         hasSpun = true;
     }

 }
```

Comment: You mean something like [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57973725/7111561) ? ;)

Comment: @derHugo I don't think it is a duplicate. "... slow to a stop at a random location.". The question is about how to achieve slow stopping. And the accepted answer from your link is about slow rotations and probabilities in fortune wheels.

Comment: @TimmyChan yes but I would say it is a more generic answer to `I am trying to write a wheel of fortune type thing.` and already includes not only the controlling of the rotation but also actually working with it with callbacks etc

Comment: @derHugo Generic answer, yes.  But it does not mean duplicate question imo. No offense though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of spinning makes it unable to smoothly stop. Setting `isSpinning` to  `false` will exactly prevent smoothing. You need some kind of formula to calculate the rotation wanted based on time. In a way such that even if the computer have low fps, the spinner will still land of the same determined destination.

Also the logic of getting random position within 5x5 square gives an uneven distribution towards to corners. The spinner will stop at the corners more often.

---

I created a Rotator script for you to inspire from. `targetSpin` is the total degrees the spinner will spin. `spinDuration` is number of seconds for the spin. And the rest is math and physics.

[image: gif of a spinner]

```cs
public class Rotater : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float spinDuration = 3f;
    public float targetSpin = 3600f;
    float initSpin = 0f;
    float initSpeed = 0f;
    float acceleration = 0f;
    float startRotTime = 0f;

    private void CalcInitSpeedingConditions()
    {
        // Here we assume constant acceleration, and ending speed must be 0.
        initSpeed = 2 * targetSpin / spinDuration;
        acceleration = -initSpeed / spinDuration;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            // targetSpin = Random.Range(1000f, 1360f);  # Use this to spin random on each press
            CalcInitSpeedingConditions();
            startRotTime = Time.time;
            initSpin = transform.localEulerAngles.y;
            StartCoroutine(Rotate());
        }
    }

    // This is fundamental physics formula
    private float GetRotationByTime(float t) => initSpeed * t + acceleration * t * t / 2;

    IEnumerator Rotate()
    {
        float t = Time.time - startRotTime;
        while (t < spinDuration) 
        {
            t = Time.time - startRotTime;
            GetRotationByTime(t);
            transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.up * (initSpin + GetRotationByTime(t) % 360);
            yield return null;
        }
        transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.up * (initSpin + GetRotationByTime(t) % 360);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the final angle, so I know which segment of the wheel it is pointing to?

Comment: The final angle is `targetSpin%360`. The unit is degrees.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
public float speed = 1.0f;
public float forceRemain = 1.0f;
public bool isSpin = false;

private Quanternion lastRot;
private float rm = forceRemain;
void Update(){
 if(isSpin){
  this.transform.rotation = new Quanternion(o, 
  lastRot.y + (speed * Time.DeltaTime), 0, // rotate right while isSpin
  lastRot.w);
 }
 else{
  if(rm > 0){
   rm -= Time.DeltaTime; //slowin down remain force
  }
  else{
   rm = forceRemain; //reset remain force
  }
 }
}
```

sorry my code is not so accurate