Implementing Animation Curve for Smooth Speed Control in Unity Coroutine Spin Wheel
I'm currently working on a Unity project where I have a spinning wheel animation implemented using a coroutine. The coroutine spins the wheel for a certain duration and stops at a specific angle. However, I'm facing difficulty integrating an animation curve to control the speed of the spin and ensure a smooth stop at the target angle.
Here's the relevant snippet of my code:
public void RotateWheel() {
    StartCoroutine(SpinWheelCoroutine());
}
private IEnumerator SpinWheelCoroutine() {
    _wheel.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    float currentSecond = 0;
    int index = Random.Range(0, 8);
    float targetAngle = (360 * 5) + index * 45;
    float startAngle = 0;
    while (currentSecond < Second) {
        currentSecond += Time.deltaTime;
        float t = currentSecond / Second;
        float currentAngle = Mathf.Lerp(startAngle, targetAngle, t);
        _wheel.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, currentAngle);
        yield return null;
    }
    Debug.Log($"index-{index}, targetAngle-{targetAngle},currentAngle-{_wheel.transform.eulerAngles.z}");

}

animation curve image

What did you try?
I experimented with integrating an animation curve into the coroutine to control the spinning speed of the wheel. My approach involved modifying the time parameter used in the Lerp function to accommodate the animation curve. However, despite these efforts, the behavior of the spinning wheel did not align with my expectations. Specifically, when incorporating the animation curve, the wheel would abruptly stop at the starting angle instead of smoothly decelerating and stopping at the target angle as intended.
What were you expecting?
My expectation was that by incorporating the animation curve, the spinning wheel's speed would be gracefully modulated according to the curve, resulting in a gradual deceleration leading to a smooth stop at the target angle. However, the observed behavior diverged significantly from this anticipated outcome, with the wheel abruptly halting at the starting angle instead of exhibiting the desired graceful deceleration and stoppage.

Show your attempt of using the animation curve. This should really just be an issue of mapping currentAngle through that curve instead of via lerp.

So currently you have a linear interpolation in
float currentAngle = Mathf.Lerp(startAngle, targetAngle, t);

which will go from startAngle to targetAngle linear meaning the is no smoothing.
A simple trick would already be to use SmoothStep which would add some ease-in and -out.
t = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, t);

or as you requested the same thing could be done using an AnimationCurve. In your case you still use a normalized t which goes linear from 0 to 1 within a duration of Second seconds. Then you want to map this onto the value via the AnimationCurve.Evaluate
t = animationCurve.Evaluate(t);

note though that for this your animation curve should still go from 0 to 1 within a second and rather look like e.g.

The horizontal axis is the time, the vertical is the value.

In general - and that's more a matter of taste - I would not use a while but rather a for loop like e.g.
for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < Second; timePassed += Time.deltaTime) 
{
    float t = currentSecond / Second;

    // [optional] your smoothing for t

    var currentAngle = Mathf.Lerp(startAngle, targetAngle, t);
    _wheel.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, currentAngle);
    yield return null;
}

// also assign the final value in order to end with clean values
_wheel.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, targetAngle);


thank for answer, but i want my spin wheel movement like
in start increase slowly then slowly decrease and then 0 like I post image in my question it possible

@mr.Umang have you tried? Because this is exactly what this should be doing

i still experimentig some thing

thanks,
if try blow code with my animation curve shape so now notice what I want to achieve but end of animation I also want it to stop at the target location
IEnumerator SpinWheelCoroutine() {
_wheel.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
float currentSecond = 0;
int index = Random.Range(0, 8);
float startAngle = 0;
while (currentSecond < Second) {
currentSecond += Time.deltaTime;
_wheel.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 10 * AnimationCurve.Evaluate(currentSecond / Second));
yield return null;
}
}

@mr.Umang makes no sense ... what is the issue with what I gave you? ^^ You can only either control the Rotate but then you have to calculate yourself in order to end up with the correct target rotation .... or you can control the absolute rotation and interpolate without directly controlling the velocity of rotation ..... is this supposed to be something like "wheel of luck"? In this case check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57973167/how-to-choose-when-fortune-wheel-stop-in-unity

hey thank you for your all suggestions
